# Имеет ли рядовой программист общее представление о том как набор цифр и символов, превращается в программу которую можно тыкать и нажимать?

Tags: java, ассемблер, компиляция, процессор, компьютерное-зрение

Имеет ли рядовой программист общее представление о работе процессора.
знает ли он что происходит после этапа компиляции. Куда оно идёт, что там происходит,сколько этапов всего проходит код, от его написания до вывода на монитор.

Comment: Вы сайтом ошиблись. Тут помогают с проблемами, а вам на опросник какой-то курс держать надо

Comment: Откройте программу по специальности "инженер-программист" любого вуза и поглядите, что программист должен знать. Вопрос слишком общий.

Answer (score 3):

По большому счету программирование как таковое является управлением массивами и переменными это если очень в общем понимании.

Все остальные функции которые существуют в языках, лишь помогают этими данными оперировать.

Насчет понимания того, как **обрабатывает процессор информацию**, множество имеет лишь очень поверхностное представление (из опыта общения со множеством программеров) они в основном используют готовые шаблоны и максимально простые языки для написания заказов (конечно речь идет не о всех специалистах). Но подавляющее большинство говорящих о том что они "супер эксперты" не смогут написать простой сервис который они уже писали используя обычный блокнот, а не навороченные среды разработки.

Полную цепочку от и до знают самые что ни на есть профи, которые разбираются в этом вопросе и кто ушел далеко в опыте разработки и сервисов и ПО и ОС.

Но главный вопрос который покажет вам одну из точек зрения **"А зачем в принципе рядовому программисту знать что там происходит внутри???"**

Он понимает как писать код, который дает результаты его уровня и этого достаточно. Также как и 95% населения Земли не понимают как работает двигатель у автомобилей, но при этом успешно на них передвигаются.